# PHP Form Multiple Lines into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

i've searched and searched and maybe i found actually the right post but nothing worked for me so sorry for any duplication but maybe someone can help me out.

I have a php that gets me a form with multiple rows (based on an form input before).

Here's the php that creates the input table:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
New report with EEM Number:<input type="text" name="eemnumber" />
<tr>
    <td>Expense Date</td>
    <td>Category</td>   
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Receipt Amount</td>
    <td>Currency</td>
    <td>Payment Amount</td>
    <td>Currency</td>   
    <td>Payment Type</td>   
    <td>Country</td>
</tr>
<?php
$rows = $_POST['rows'];
$n = 0;
while($n < $rows)
         {
         $n++;
         ?>
         <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="expensedate"/><br /></td>
    <td><select name="category">
        <option value="AirFare">AirFare</option> />
        <option value="AutoRental">Auto Rental - Employee</option> />
        <option value="DailyAllowance">Daily Allowance Standard</option> />
        <option value="Gasoline">Gasoline - Auto Rental</option> />
        <option value="Lodging">Lodging (Hotel) - Room / Tax</option> />
        <option value="Meals">Meals / Entertain - HP only, Travel</option> />
        <option value="Misc">Miscellaneous</option> />
        <option value="Taxi">Taxi / Subway / Bus / Train</option> />
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="vendor"/><br /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="receiptamount"/>
    </td>
    <td><select name="currrec">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option> />
        <option value="SEK">SEK</option> />
        <option value="USD">USD</option> />
        </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="paymentamount"/>
    </td>
    <td><select name="currpay">
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option> />
        <option value="SEK">SEK</option> />
        <option value="USD">USD</option> />
    </td>
    <td><select name="paytype">
        <option value="cash">Cash</option> />
        <option value="cc">Credit Card</option> />
        <br/>
    </td>
    <td><select name="country">
        <option value="DE">Germany</option> />
        <option value="SE">Sweden</option> />
        <option value="US">USA</option> />
        <br/>
    </td>
</tr>
<?PHP
}
?>
  </table>
 </div>
<p>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<!-- End of FORM -->
<a href="./index.php">Back</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

So once all data was entered I click on Submit and would of course like to get every line into my DB. Here's the script i tried do use but only gets me the last...

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$eemnumber=$_POST['expensedate'];
$expensedate=$_POST['expensedate'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$vendor=$_POST['vendor'];
$receiptamount=$_POST['receiptamount'];
$currrec=$_POST['currrec'];
$paymentamount=$_POST['paymentamount'];
$currpay=$_POST['currpay'];
$paytype=$_POST['paytype'];
$eemnumber=$_POST['eemnumber'];
$country=$_POST['country']; 

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_eem_data 
(ExpenseDate, Category, Vendor, ReceiptAmount, CurrRec, PaymentAmount, CurrPay, PayType, EEMNumber, Country)
VALUES 
$expensedate, 
$category, 
$vendor,
$receiptamount,
$currrec,
$paymentamount,
$currpay,
$paytype,
$eemnumber,
$country)";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_close($con);

header("location:index.php");

?>
```

Anyone any clue?

Thanks!!!

Comment: he want you to look how nice his code. To read it and see if there is some errors.

Comment: you should have differents names

Comment: also be carefull, Sql Injection...you should do some processing on your POST variables

Comment: "Only gets you the last"? The last What??  To be honest there is so much wrong with that code it is difficult to know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change form Structure and form Fields

```
        <?php
    $rows = $_POST['rows'];
    $n = 0;
    while($n < $rows)
             {
             $n++;
             ?>
             <tr>
                  <td><input type="date" name="expensedate[<?echo $n?>]"/><br /></td>
        <td><select name="category">
            <option value="AirFare">AirFare</option> />
            <option value="AutoRental">Auto Rental - Employee</option> />
            <option value="DailyAllowance">Daily Allowance Standard</option> />
            <option value="Gasoline">Gasoline - Auto Rental</option> />
            <option value="Lodging">Lodging (Hotel) - Room / Tax</option> />
            <option value="Meals">Meals / Entertain - HP only, Travel</option> />
            <option value="Misc">Miscellaneous</option> />
            <option value="Taxi">Taxi / Subway / Bus / Train</option> />
            <br/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vendor[<?echo $n?>]"/><br /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="receiptamount[<?echo $n?>]"/>
        </td>
        <td><select name="currrec">
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option> />
            <option value="SEK">SEK</option> />
            <option value="USD">USD</option> />
            </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="paymentamount[<?echo $n?>]"/>
        </td>
        <td><select name="currpay[<?echo $n?>]">
            <option value="EUR">EUR</option> />
            <option value="SEK">SEK</option> />
            <option value="USD">USD</option> />
        </td>
        <td><select name="paytype[<?echo $n?>]">
            <option value="cash">Cash</option> />
            <option value="cc">Credit Card</option> />
            <br/>
        </td>
        <td><select name="country[<?echo $n?>]">
            <option value="DE">Germany</option> />
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option> />
            <option value="US">USA</option> />
            <br/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?PHP
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="rows" value="<?echo $n?>" />
```

Then apply similar loop to fetch those values.
You also need to have hidden variable which stores total number of rows you have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing an open parenthesis `(` in your SQL right after `VALUES`.

Fix it and hopefully it will work: `VALUES ( . . . )`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, run this test:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="key" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="key" value="2" />
```

PHP:

```
<?
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And then run this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="key[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="key[]" value="2" />
```

PHP:

```
<?
  print_r($_POST);
?>
```

See if you can make any conclusions with this, and let me know what you think.

Comment: Does not change anything to be honest. I'm getting the same output

Answer (score 0):

You are generating form fields based on the number of `$rows` received from the Request.

```
<form ...  <!- this line was missing in your code -->
$rows = $_POST['rows'];
while($n < $rows)
...
</form>
```

And after submit, you are not reading parameters into arrays.

```
$eemnumber=$_POST['expensedate']; /* this is wrong again */
$expensedate=$_POST['expensedate'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$vendor=$_POST['vendor'];
```

Which lead the last value from the submitted array values assigned to the variable in concern.

And hence you see that only last row read and pushed into DB.

Change your code accordingly and it should be working.

***Refer to***:

- [*PHP: Reading POST data with arrays*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer although I currently dont get it. You said that `$rows=$_POST['rows']` bla bla is missing but it's in the code... What is it that i miss?

Comment: naming convention for variables in the `while` loop is wrong. But can be handled, when submitted to other server script file.

Comment: Refer to the URL I mentioned in the answer to understand how to store param values into an array from request object.